# Neural network not converging on clear linearly seperable problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am developing a neural network in Keras and I want to test to make sure it works. The feature set is obviously linearly seperable ('A' and 'N' in the below figure) but for some reason when I run my neural network using heart rate variability (HRV in the figure) as the sole feature, it doesn't think the positive training examples ('A' training examples) are unique:

[image: clearly linearly separable]

My neural network architecture is a simple one:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(None, X_train.shape[1]),
           activation='sigmoid'))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=decay_rate)

model.compile(loss=loss_fn, optimizer=opt, metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

When I test the accuracy using a confusion matrix, the NN overfits to the negative training examples:

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

     0.0       0.72      1.00      0.84     20774
     1.0       0.00      0.00      0.00      8126

accuracy                           0.72     28900
macro avg       0.36      0.50      0.42     28900
weighted avg       0.52      0.72      0.60     28900
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit: Additional hyperparamters**

```
Training vector shape:(67432, 1, 1)
Example of first element:[[72.710655]

loss_fn = 'binary_crossentropy'
learning_rate = 1e-2
decay_rate = 1e-8
n_epochs = 10 (have varied this but still converges to negative training example)
```

**Edit: Additional information**

I wanted to include how I formatting my arrays in case the issue is with that:

```
X_train = np.asarray(X_train).reshape(
    X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])

X_test = np.asarray(X_test).reshape(
    X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])
```

Comment: Could you please upload your training parameters such as loss function, learning rates, epochs etc. (everything which you've defined variables for in the last three lines)

Comment: I've made the changes to the question by adding the relevant parameters.

Comment: I saw your previous answer that the data was incorrectly labelled. Is this issue now resolved?

Comment: No it has not. I wanted to double check if that were the issue, because otherwise I would be wasting everyone's time. It is not an issue with labelling.

Comment: It's tough to say without working on the data myself. Maybe the class imbalance is causing this, but I don't think so. Have you tried a simpler architecture? Yours is quite complex for such a simple separation. Theoretically you only need a single 'hidden' neuron with a thresholding function to separate these two classes

Comment: As I had mentioned in my question I am purely testing the neural network architecture, as my real data has 100 features. Even if I switch to 1 layer with 1 node the same result occurs.

Comment: Yeah I don't really see a reason why it wouldn't work. Have you checked the distribution of samples from the two classes between the training and test set?

Comment: I use scikitlearn's train_test_split, so the training and testing examples are pretty much both imbalanced. No luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have imbalanced data you may want to use class_weight in model.fit

```py
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), class_weight=class_weight)
```

Here `class_weight` is a dictionary. One option you can try is to set the class weight inversely proportional to the class size, i.e. the number of data points of each class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used sklearn's 'class_weight' in order to set the class weight to balance out the losses but the same issue occurs. I also set it manually to something extremely large (500, 5000) and no luck. I'm wondering now if somehow my training features and labels were somehow mixed up, as that is the only think I can possibly think of.